# set textbox value with php variable

Tags: php, html

I'm using **php 7**. I trying to put php variable value into html textbox, but it doesn't work.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <title></title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <form action="two.php" method="POST">
            <input type="text" name="id_brg" value="<?php echo $_GET['id_brg'] ?>">
        </form>
    </body>
</html>
```

two.php

```
<?php 

$id_brg = $_POST[uniqidi()];

?>
```

Comment: if your method in the form is POST you can't use $_GET to take the value... you should use `$_POST['id_brg']`

Comment: i did, but it doesn't work too

Comment: how do you submit the form? you also need a submit button...

Comment: i want to display uniqid() when load html form. so it must display before i press the submit button

Comment: I didn't undestand well what you need. How can you have a value from the form if you don't submit it?

Comment: your first page is in `.html` or in `.php`.?

Comment: uniqid() will generate random id and i have to display  value of the id from uniqid()

Comment: @GyandeepSharma .html

Comment: save it with .php extension

Comment: @GyandeepSharma if i save html file in php, do i need to <?php ?> tag at the beginning and the end of tag html ?

Comment: no... Just save that file in `.php`. You'll get the output...

Comment: @GyandeepSharma thanks ... I got what I wanted

Comment: Your welcome.....

Answer (score 1):

I'm not entirely sure what you're trying to do. But I'm pretty sure you want to set the value of a form field to a value from the URI query string.

The way you've done this is correct in the first snippet is correct, but your issue is that you're using POST and not for your form method. Here is how you should do it if you want it for both types.

```
<?php
    if ($_POST['id_brg']) {
        $id_brg = $_POST['id_brg'];
    } else if ($_GET['id_brg']) {
        $id_brg = $_GET['id_brg'];
    } else {
        $id_brg = uniqid();
    }

?>

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <title></title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <form action="two.php" method="POST">
           <input type="text" name="id_brg" value="<?php echo $id_brg; ?>">
        </form>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: it have same problem with me .. textbox only display "<?php echo $id_brg ?>" not the uniqid()

Comment: Make sure you're file is a PHP file, and not an HTML one. That sounds like the file isn't being runt through the pre-proccessor.

Comment: if i save html file in php, do i need to <?php ?> tag at the beginning and the end of tag html ?

Comment: yes. The difference between a .html and .php file is only that the code written between <?php and ?> get's run. PHP code will not be processed in a .html file, only a .php one.

Answer (score 1):

Consider use POST method on your form.

```
<input type="text" name="id_brg" value="<?php echo $_POST['id_brg']; ?>">
```

You miss semicolon on the code you provide below.

```
$_POST['id_brg'];
```

Comment: i correct the code but still ..showing "<?php echo $_GET['id_brg']; ?>" i my textbox

Comment: @usersaturintan are you sure both of your file using .php ?

Comment: yup, I have fixed it

Answer (score 0):

one.php

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
   <title></title>
</head>
<body>
       <input type="text" name="id" value="
       <?php
       include 'two.php';
       echo $id_brg;

       ?> "
       >
</body>
</html>
```

two.php

```
<?php 

   $id_brg = uniqid();

?>
```

Comment: Rintan, **achieving only the result should not be the goal in the world of coding, try to learn the better approach too.** As you are newbie I would love to help you learn the better ways so that it helps in developing the good base.

Comment: okk .. teach me how to write the right code with the same result bcz i have no idea to create the result like that with better code :')

Comment: For that, you have clear me exactly what you want to achieve? What's the scenario you are writing code for. Kindly explain to me that, then only I can tell you the better approach.

Comment: i mean maybe i can compare yours and mine, so maybe i can learn something from the beauty of your code

Comment: Until and unless you clear your requirement I can't write a better code. kindly explain what you want to achieve?

Comment: i just want to display random id from uniqid() into textbox

Comment: For only this much of requirement create a single PHP file, **no need for two PHP files**, **no need of including**. Simply write this `<input type="text" name="id_brg" value="<?php echo uniqid(); ?>">`. If still you need more knowledge you can skype me. :) Will be happy to help you

Comment: i need to create two php files bcz in two.php i'll write sql query, and i think it wil geting mess if i mix html, query, and php